# Mark script as already defined in require js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I had to move some scripts to synchronous load through bundle, and I want to set those scripts as already defined, so require.js would not ask server for them in next calls.

Let me explain:

1. I had some scripts that were required everywhere, e.g. i18n, and jQuery. So I have hundreds if calls all around the project such as

`require(['jquery', 'i18n', 'commonjs', ...`

2. I bundled `'jquery'`, `'i18n'`, `'commonjs'` into one script `core.js` which now is inserted in layout `<script src="/core.js"></script>`

All functions from jQuery, i18n now can be accesses globally, without need of requiring them. I want to specifically say to reuire.js that those scripts are already loaded, something which `bundles` should do.

I've read [article](http://webroo.org/articles/2014-03-30/using-the-new-require-js-bundles-feature/) about using bundles and tried to put
bundle in my config file

```
bundles: {
    'core': ['jquery', 'i18n', 'commonjs']
}
```

but it doesn't work, there lots of mistakes fallen and as I understood the only way to use bundle is to use r.js which optimizes js and folders.

Actually, all I want is to set some scripts as already loaded for require.js. Is there a dirty way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no configuration option to mark a script as already defined. What you can do is to call `define` yourself with a module name and an appropriate return value. For instance, if you load jQuery with a `script` element before you start loading any module through RequireJS, you can do:

```
define("jquery", [], function () {
  return $;
});
```

The code above makes it so that whenever any module requires the module `jquery`, they get the value of `$`. I normally place such modules like the one just before my call to `require.config`. It's just a convenient place for them.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks!